# How can I track changes on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to build a solution that will track a page, then alert me when a certain keyword is added.

For example, track https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies and check once a day to see if "Google" is added to the page. It would make the most sense from a user's perspective for this to be a chrome extension.

It's a project I want to build and I'm a relatively new developer who has learned js/react so far. This will be my first project on my own. I'm trying to break it down by features/tasks and not sure how to do this part. Thank you!

Comment: The Chrome extension would only know of changes when you visit the actual page. Otherwise, if you want to receive alerts without the user having gone to the page, you would need to set up a server that would visit the page for you. You could do this using something like [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) to check if Google is on your page (if the page has a public API, you could use that instead). You can use a cron to schedule the check daily. Your chrome extension could ping your server for updates and then do whatever it needs to show an alert to the user

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you. I'm not familiar with any, but I'll look into these. So I can create the extension and use puppeteer to somehow check the webpage with the help of cron. Maybe I can use a webhook to trigger emails via zapier? Tbh this is all a bit ahead of where I'm at with my learning so if you have any additional resources to look into I'd appreciat it. Thanks!

Comment: The first time I came across puppeteer was when I saw [this](https://youtu.be/rWc0xqroY4U) video. If I recall correctly, he scrapes Twitter to get his followers using axios. He also uses a cron to schedule the scrape so that it occurs every X days. So now that I think about it, you might not need puppeteer for this and instead might just be able to fetch the page contents by making a GET request to your URL from your server (you may need to use puppeteer if your page is client-side rendered).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script with a web-scraping library such as [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to run once a day.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this and the github link. Got a lot to learn :)